# BAT-file: strange SET(?) behavior

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, environment-variables

I have following batch file code:

```
@echo off
SET INSTALL_PATH=c:\program files\
:ask_again
if exist "%INSTALL_PATH%" (
SET /P PATH_EXISTS_ANSWER=Path exists, overwrite?[y/n/default:n]
if not defined PATH_EXISTS_ANSWER (
    echo You chose default action^(N^). Try another installation path.
    echo.
    goto default
    )
if /I "%PATH_EXISTS_ANSWER%"=="n" (
    echo You chose not to use existing folder. Try another installation path.
    echo.
    goto noc
    )   
if /I "%PATH_EXISTS_ANSWER%"=="y" (
    echo You chose to overwrite existing folder. Existing files will be overwritten.
    echo.
    goto yesc
    )
echo Please choose Y or N
echo.
goto ask_again
)

:yesc
echo you said yes
goto end

:default
echo you said default
goto end

:noc
echo you said no
goto end

:end
```

And it's OK when i choose default action just pressing Enter. But when i use N or Y key, value of PATH_EXISTS_ANSWER seems to be undefined, script goes for another loop and then, no matter what i answer,  script somewhy uses previous answer.
For example if i answer Y script asks again and if i choose N it types "you said yes".
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: i have suspicion, that CMD.exe evaluates real value of variable when cursor goes out of IF block. but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the following after `@echo off`:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
```

Then, when you refer to `PATH_EXISTS_ANSWER`, instead of enclosing it in percent marks, (`%`) enclose it in exclamation marks. (`!`) like this: `!PATH_EXISTS_ANSWER!`

I tested it, and it works.

Comment: Sure, glad to be of help. Another happy customer. (By the way, I accept upvotes, too!)

Answer (score 1):

The variable is set, thus defined after the 1st execution; run the file then in the console type `echo %PATH_EXISTS_ANSWER%` and you will see what you entered last.

to prevent this either set `PATH_EXISTS_ANSWER` to empty (`[]`) at the start or better add [`SETLOCAL`](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html).

Comment: Maybe i'm dumb, but setting variable to empty didn't work. Though setlocal did. Thanks!